# how to get specific cookie value from swi prolog http request

Tags: http, cookies, get, prolog, swi-prolog

SWI prolog http server libraries provide a way to elegantly access the incoming http get query parameters / term:

```
http_parameters(Request, [term(QueryTerm, [])]),
```

Is there an equivalent method that allows retrieval of a specific cookie name/value.

eg. of fictitious predicate I wish to exist:

```
http_parameters(Request, [cookie('my_cookieName', MyCookieValue), [])]),
```

`http_parameters` seems to only access the 'search(X)' value (ie form data only).

As the request object is just a list, I could do something like:

```
nth1(_, Request, cookie(CookieL)),
```

Then parse out the name/value pair from CookieL... it's just ugly, if there is a predicate that already goes straight there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having looked at the http_parameters source, I can see that prolog will do all the heavy lifting for the name/value pair parsing of the cookie list.

So having set up an http handler:

```
:- http_handler(root(.), myroothandler, []).
```

And define that predicate that will automatically know about the swi http Request object (since it has been defined as a handler):

```
myroothandler(Request) :-
  http_cookie_value(Request, 'mycookiename', Value).
```

Then the new cookie extractor itself:

```
% extracts a cookie value from the swi http request object
% fails if either no cookie list in request or cookie Name not found
http_cookie_value(Request, Name, Value) :-

    % cookie list must exist in the request, and will live in CookieList
    memberchk(cookie(CookieList), Request),

    % find one cookie in the cookie list whose Name is Value.
    nth1(_, CookieList, Name=Value).
```